# How to delete IBMCloud database instances with having same names

Tags: postgresql, jenkins, ibm-cloud

[image]I am having following same named instances as shown in image
Names are as follows:-

1. stage-tas-postgres-service
2. stage-tas-postgres-service
3. stage-tas-postgres-service
   And I am tried to delete it from three dots option but since the stage environment is blocked for deletion activity.

I have referred the below link for deletion[IBM Cloud Deletion DB](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cloud-databases?topic=cloud-databases-deprovisioning)

We have IAM identity and through which tried to delete the instance from Jenkins job
and the command I tried to delete after successful login into IAM user is as follows :-

```
stage("Deleting resource") {
  ibmcloud "resource service-instance-delete stage-tas-postgres-service --recursive"
}
```

The problem is this job ends with success results, but did not delete the instance.
I am using only 3rd from all list and other two are unused show in image and in above list.

Is there any way to delete the DB from `crn` or `deployment` id

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says that you do not have the required permissions to delete the database. You can see and probably use that database instance, but not delete it.

It seems you are not the account owner or someone with administrator privilege. Therefore, someone else needs to delete the service.

For the future, you could set up a serviceID with the required permissions. Then, use a script which uses the serviceID for login to IBM Cloud and deletion of that service.

Comment: Sorry to reply very late. using rights it is done

Comment: if it is the right answer, please mark as answered

Comment: Mine reputations are less than required numbers, and hence accepting answer does  not publicly visible. sorry for this.